# Get product category on home page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, categories, getcaretpos

I am using this code in `latest_content.tpl` file to get category name. But it is not displaying category name. How can I get category name in opencart.

```
 $categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);
if ($categories)
   $categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[0]['category_id']);
$this->data['category_title'] = $categories_info['name'];
echo echo $category_title;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `catalog/controller/module/latest.php`, before `$this->data['products'][] = array(` add:

```
$categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($result['product_id']);
if($categories){
    $categories_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[0]['category_id']);
    $category_title = $categories_info['name'];
}else{
    $category_title = '';
}
```

Update `$this->data['products'][]` array as below:

```
 $this->data['products'][] = array(
            'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
            'category_title' => $category_title,
            'thumb'      => $image,
            'name'       => $result['name'],
            'price'      => $price,
            'special'    => $special,
            'rating'     => $rating,
            'reviews'    => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
            'href'       => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
        );
```

Now in `latest.tpl`, you'll get the category title as `$product['category_title']`.

**Additional information:** - Model functions should be called within controllers.  The variables defined `$this->data['variable_name']` in controller can be accessed in template file as `$variable_name`.

Have a niceday !!